# SSH command behaving differently in expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, expect

I am creating a script that is executed from host-A to connect to a remote host-b, runs a bash script (which generates monitoring data from top etc.) on host-b, and appends the output back to a file on host-A. While I use ssh to connect, I will not be using ssh-keys as there are simply way too many servers in the environment.

My expect script:

```
"#!/usr/bin/expect

"#!/usr/bash

set timeout 10

set hostname [sample_hostname]

set user "(sample_user)"

set password "(sample_password)"


spawn ssh $user@$hostname /path/to/bash/script/script.sh | cat >> /tmp/file

expect "Password:"

send "$password\r";

expect "$"

====================================
```

The above script appends the output of the bash script into host-B /tmp/file instead of the desired host-A /tmp/file. How can I change to have script append to host-A instead of host-b?

P.S.

1. manually logging into host-A
2. cd to script location
3. run ssh user@hostname /path/to/script/script.sh | cat >> /tmp/file on host-A
4. cat /tmp/file

Above manual steps performs as desired; hence my idea that problem is with bash in expect.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Regards,

Alan

Comment: If you DO get `expect` working, I recommend you use it *once* to populate your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, then drop expect in favour of key-based authentication.

Comment: I think the problem is that you expect `spawn` to be running a shell for you. I don't believe it does that. Try the redirection on the outside of the `expect` script on host-A. Also why `| cat`? What does that pipe do for you?

Comment: It's just behaving different from your expectation. All the parameters in the `spawn` statement is treated as a parameter to the first argument `ssh` which makes redirection part of the spawned remote session. Your question is a variation of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220447/how-to-capture-expect-output-using-spawn-and-sftp-under-solaris

Comment: ghoti - thanks. Unfortunately for now storing ssh keys in the boxes is out of the question since we have 50+ boxes and wouldn't be very scalable with addition of new boxes.

Comment: Etan - Tried taking out the | cat; script is still appending to host-b and the >> is appending the bash output instead of the script's output. I think I'll need it to both write to the host-A and display the right output. I'll take the ssh out of the expect and see. Thanks!

Comment: Etan - oops my mistake, output is still good without | cat. Still writing to host-B though, which I'm thinking alvits has the reason there. Trying Dinesh's method from below answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to get just the output of that script, then proceed with the following way.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set timeout 10

set hostname host
set user dinesh
set password pwd
set script "/home/dinesh/mypgms/demo.sh"
spawn ssh $user@$hostname
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
expect "\\\$"; # Matching the literal dollar prompt sign of terminal
send "$script\r"
expect -re "\r\n(.*)\\\$"; # Matching the output
# Getting first sub-match as result
puts "\nResult : --->$expect_out(1,string)"
```

This will give the output as

```
dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:~/stackoverflow$ ./alan 
spawn ssh dinesh@host
dinesh@host's password: 
Last login: Tue Apr 21 13:30:35 2015 
[dinesh@ ~]$ /home/dsivaji/mypgms/demo.sh
{\"INFO\":0}\0\r
{\"INFO\":0}\0\r
[dinesh@~]$ 
Result : --->{\"INFO\":0}\0\r
{\"INFO\":0}\0\r
[dinesh@~]
dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:~/stackoverflow$
```

Note that the result as

```
{\"INFO\":0}\0\r
{\"INFO\":0}\0\r
[dinesh@~]
```

Since we are matching upto the prompt `$`, it contains till that point. You can customize the regular expression based on the shell output also.

Comment: Makes sense so far. I'll test to see if the put appends to file in host-A. Will update!

Comment: Added the expect -re and put $expect_out(0,string) commands into the expect script and worked! though required modification of your solution which is to keep the ssh $user@$hostname /path/script.sh line but taking the redirection outside the expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the expect/set method beacuse of the password.

I found another application called sshpass once installed you can just run the command like this inside your bash.

```
sshpass -p PASSWORDHERE ssh user@hostname /path/to/bash/script/script.sh | cat >> /tmp/file
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass

enjoy

Comment: For posterity and reference, [sshpass is also available for FreeBSD](http://freshports.org/security/sshpass).

Comment: Max, this is really cool! Yes, that's the reason for me using expect. I'm seeing if I can get it to work via expect method, but sshpass is something I'll definitely look into.